# How did Japonism, if at all, affect manga/anime?

Tags: culture, manga-history

While researching my own question [How important was the invention of blue towards anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/42351/1458), I landed relatively quickly on [Hokusai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokusai), which was one of the key instigators of [Japonisme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japonism).

> Japonisme, is the study of Japanese art and artistic talent. Japonisme affected fine arts, sculpture, architecture, performing arts and decorative arts throughout Western culture

Although Japonisme mainly influenced the European art, it also had an effect on the Japanese art scene.

So did Japonisme also lead to, or influence the creation of manga/anime as we know it nowadays?

Comment: Japonism, or as the French refer to it, japonisme, refers to the incorporation of either iconography or concepts of Japanese art into European art and design. Much of Hokusai’s popular acclaim in the west is thanks his 15-volume illustrated series called "Hokusai Manga" . In the west, it started this japonism craze and gave more or less birth the name to a early concept of we now know as manga. So is not so much japonism influenced manga, but rather gave exposure to pre-war manga in the west, influencing various art movements in that era, imo.

Comment: This is more so in scope as an art history question than one specifically about pre-war manga imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no. Beyond making the world aware of the early, pre-war concept of manga, there is little to nothing to do with modern post-war manga. The influences are just a footnote in history in terms of European art movements.

Post-war manga we know as manga today is starkly different from  the prototypical  manga of the type, such a the compiled work of Hokusa Manga.